# Getting current size of WPF controls

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, size

I have Image control in my Window. The size of this Image control is set to "Auto".

```
<Image x:Name="videoImg" Stretch="Fill" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" />
```

When i try to get access, it returns 0. How to see real size of this control? It resizes with window.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use `.ActualHeight` and `.ActualWidth` to get the rendered `Height`/`Width` of a control

Comment: @TimurMustafaev How are you trying to get the values? Through code behind? Through a binding? And when are you trying to get the values? The control has to be rendered before `ActualHeigh` and `ActualWidth` will return a size.

Comment: I call new form from my MainWindow. On this new form there are fiew controls and one of them is Image. After window loaded i try to get size like this: _imageControl.ActualWidth or _imageControl.ActualHeigh

Comment: @TimurMustafaev That should work providing the image is Visible (invisible objects do not have a render size). Test getting those values in a Button Click event to be sure the images has finished rendering. Another set of values you can look at is `.RenderSize.Height` and `.RenderSize.Width`

Answer (score 3):

The thing is, the `Width` and `Height` properties let you express the *desired size*, whereas what you want is the *rendered size* - which can be accessed (but not set) using the [`ActualWidth`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.actualwidth.aspx) and [`ActualHeight`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.actualheight.aspx) properties.

It should be noted that these aren't static values either, that is, once set they are not necessarily going to be the same forever after, as it will be re-evaluated upon each rendering sequence...

> Because [ActualHeight / ActualWidth] is a calculated value, you should be aware that
>   there could be multiple or incremental reported changes to it as a
>   result of various operations by the layout system. The layout system
>   may be calculating required measure space for child elements,
>   constraints by the parent element, and so on.

So, depending on your requirements, you might want to consider re-evaluating your data at appropriate points, perhaps when the containing control resizes, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

While some of WPF controls fill up all available space when laid out and rendered, the others don't.
Specifically, the Image control is not of a kind that establishes its size on its own, i.e., in cases when you do not specify control's size explicitly with width/height attributes or the like.

But the Grid control fills up all available space when lacking size-defining attributes. The Page/Window template in Visual Studio has a Grid control as a child of a Page/Window root control, and when the user starts to put controls on a page in a graphical editor, the user-added controls first become children of this Grid control.

If you have used the VS template, and your Image control is a child of the said Grid control, name your Grid with an x:Name attribute, and you can use the Grid's ActualWidth/Height properties for your needs in a code-behind, because the image control grows up to its parent Grid size -- provided you do not specify its size explicitly or otherwise, i.e., setting the Image content.

By the way, the sizing behavior of built-in controls can be changed. You can modify a control and override corresponding dependency properties. See, for example, https://stackoverflow.com/a/6094993 .